# Why do airlines prohibit having two infants in the same row?

Tags: air-travel, airlines, regulations, children

If a family is travelling with infants under 2 years old, these infants will not need a seat (of course you can buy them a seat if you want), and they can just sit in their parents' laps. Given that, why do airlines prohibit two infants from sitting in the same row (for example Seat A,B and C) at one side of the aisle? Why is it that one of the parent has to move to another row or to the other side of the row?

Comment: So that one crying baby does not set off a chain reaction of multiple crying babies and result in heat death of the universe.

Comment: Err, two friends have just flown from France to NZ on Air Singapore, and had two in the same row? Are you sure this is all airlines?

Comment: @markmayo both of the infants are in their laps?

Comment: Anyway, the larger jets _may_ have two extra oxygen masks of the row has 4 or 5 seats next to each other (usually the middle set of seats). But in general, most airplanes have only 1 extra mask for each set of seats in in a row (one of the left side, one for the right and one in the middle) while in some narrow jets there could be only one extra mask in either left of right side. That's the common thing.

Comment: I recently had a 12 hour flight with two infants (one was mine) sitting in bulkhead seats, and another infant in the same row on a bassinet. Maybe it depends on the airline?

Comment: For safety reasons yes maybe. However, it is frustrating that airlines will say that they allow 2 infants for 1 adult (the other infant should have a seat and child ticket). But when you try to book a flight, you cannot book the infant with child seat because they ask for the child's birthdate. If I put in a fake birthdate for my child that could mean trouble in the airport. Even calling customer support doesn't help. Ridiculous.

Comment: Taking young children on a plane causes Autism! Make sure you keep you child safe and don't fly for the first 3 years if you can help it.

Comment: @Andrew Two infants **in bulkhead seats**--no problem.  They have the oxygen masks that come with the seat.  The problem is lap infants.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This is prohibited for safety reasons. Each row has one extra oxygen mask (there are exceptions, some rows have no extra masks and they will be marked somehow). If more than one infant is seated in a parent's lap and the oxygen masks were to be used one of the row occupants will have no oxygen mask to use.

Usually the reservation system/agents will avoid such a situation but it could happen that a family with two infants will be given boarding passes in one row, the cabin crew then will move one of the parents along with one of the infants to the other side of the row or to another row.

**Update**: in some larger jets the set of seats in the middle (4 or 5 seats) may have two extra oxygen masks, in that case two infants can accompany their parents in their laps.